# Reverse Label Encoding giving error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I label encoded my categorical data into numerical data using label encoder

```
data['Resi'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(data['Resi'])
```

But I when I try to find how they are mapped internally using

```
list(LabelEncoder.inverse_transform(data['Resi']))
```

I am getting  below error

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-419ab6db89e2> in <module>()
----> 1 list(LabelEncoder.inverse_transform(data['Resi']))

TypeError: inverse_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

How to fix this

**Sample data**

```
Resi
IP
IP
IP
IP
IP
IE
IP
IP
IP
IP
IP
IPD
IE
IE
IP
IE
IP
IP
IP
```

Comment: Can you please share some data? What does the `LabelEncoder.classes_` shows?

Comment: @VivekKumar, updated the sample data in question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check [label encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#label-encoding):

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit([1, 2, 2, 6])
LabelEncoder()
>>> le.classes_
array([1, 2, 6])
>>> le.transform([1, 1, 2, 6])
array([0, 0, 1, 2])
>>> le.inverse_transform([0, 0, 1, 2])
array([1, 1, 2, 6])
```

And for your solution:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder().fit(data['Resi'])
data['Resi'] = le.transform(data['Resi'])
print (data.tail())
    Resi
14     1
15     0
16     1
17     1
18     1

L = list(le.inverse_transform(data['Resi']))
print (L)
['IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IE', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 
 'IP', 'IP', 'IPD', 'IE', 'IE', 'IP', 'IE', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP']
```

EDIT:

```
d = dict(zip(le.classes_, le.transform(le.classes_)))
print (d)
{'IE': 0, 'IPD': 2, 'IP': 1}
```

Comment: @jezral, How do I find which label corresponds which category.  I.e IP =0, IPD=1, so on

Answer (score 1):

You are not storing the LabelEncoder() object anywhere. You need to save it like this:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
```

And then call `fit()`, or `transform()`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

ls = ['IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IE', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP', 'IPD', 'IE', 'IE', 'IP', 'IE', 'IP', 'IP', 'IP']

data = pd.DataFrame(np.array(ls).reshape(-1,1), columns=['Resi'])

le = LabelEncoder()
data['Resi'] = le.fit_transform(data['Resi'])

df['resi'] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df['resi'])
list(le.inverse_transform(data['Resi']))

Out: 
['IP',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IE',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IPD',
 'IE',
 'IE',
 'IP',
 'IE',
 'IP',
 'IP',
 'IP']
```

Comment: How can I find which label correspond to which category

Answer (score 0):

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()  
encoder.inverse_transform(data['Resi'])
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.