# Preserving dtype as category after integer encoding in Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame read from csv that has some columns with string values but are actually `object` types. Because they are categorical, I convert them into `category` and then into integer representation, and then I am fitting a random forest regressor.

```
for col in df_raw.select_dtypes(include='object'):
    df_raw[col] = df_raw[col].astype('category')
    df_raw[col] = df_raw[col].cat.codes #not 'category' type anymore.
```

The problem is if I do this, then the `dtype` is immediately converted to `int` and I lose the `cat` information, which I need later.

For example, after the first line in the loop, I can run `df_raw[col].cat`, and I would get the indexed categories as expected. But once the second line is executed, the column `dtype` changes to `int8`, I will get the error:

> Can only use .cat accessor with a 'category' dtype`

which, in a way makes perfect sense, since it's dtype is `int8`.

**Is it possible to preserve the category encoding information in the same DataFrame and at the sametime have integer encodings in place to fit the regressor? How?**

Comment: Please give an example input

Comment: A more precise [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would indeed help to precisely nail the problem with the answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you want your (now correctly) integer coded columns to be a categorical dtype? The primary reason for column dtypes is for pandas/numpy to process them efficiently...

Comment: @roganjosh I have updated the question, is it complete yet.

Comment: @G.Anderson, only because I want to be able to lookup the encodings later, without having to track an extra set of columns or a new variable. Or say, to easily reorder again.

Comment: This sounds like an X->Y problem. You may want to read through the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068468/reverse-label-encoding-giving-error) about reversing the sklearn labelencoder, because just having a column of numbers as objects won't necessarily solve your actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Simple idea**

Why won't you use a derived column in the regressor fitting, e.g.:

```
df_raw[col + '_calculated'] = df_raw[col].cat.codes
```

In this way you have both: a categorical column `col` that does not change this feature and a "calculated" column with `int`s as needed for further processing?

**2. More clever approach**

Another approach could be that you wrap the dataframe before passing it to the `fit` method in such a way that regressor accesses `.cat.codes` instead of the categorical value directly:

```
def access_wrapper(dframe, col):
   yield from dframe[col].cat.codes

fit(..., access_wrapper(df, col))
```

In this way you do not affect the dataframe at all and do not copy the values from `df[col]` at the expense of calling the `dframe[col].cat.codes` per each access to the value (which should be fairly quick).

Comment: If I'm getting you correctly, then I'm essentially adding an extra column by following the above step. I have around 20 categorical columns, that means 20 new ones added to the dataframe. That's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: Please see the 2nd approach I am suggesting. A form of accessor should be of help here for you. And it is fairly efficient (particularly memory-wise).

Comment: I like the 2nd approach, and answers my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
train.col = pd.Categorical(train.col)
```

To make it go back to categorical type from int

And then run

```
train.col.cat.codes
```